# Dynamic double animation end - XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have a progress bar that I have styled to look like the indeterminate windows ui progress bar, with the 5 ellipses going from side to side,
the animation is based inside of a canvas, the problem is my application is resolution and size independent, thus the canvas's width property is dynamic, I want to make the animation's end property (Canvas.Left) to dynamically change to the width of the canvas minus the with of the ellipse. I have tried to bind it somehow (I am still a beginner at binding) so I always get a runtime error...
Can someone please help?

Canvas:

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Height="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                            <Ellipse Name="ellipse" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarEllipse}" Width="9" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
                            <Ellipse Name="ellipse1" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarEllipse}" Width="9" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
                            <Ellipse Name="ellipse2" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarEllipse}" Width="9" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
                            <Ellipse Name="ellipse3" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarEllipse}" Width="9" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
                            <Ellipse Name="ellipse4" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarEllipse}" Width="9" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
                        </Canvas>
```

And The Story Board:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1260" KeySpline="0,1,1,0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1260" KeySpline="0,0.8,1,0.2" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1260" KeySpline="0,0.6,1,0.4" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse3">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1260" KeySpline="0,0.4,1,0.6" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse4">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1260" KeySpline="0,0.2,1,0.8" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.5" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.5" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse3">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.5" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.5" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse4">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.5" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
```

I want to change the storyboard values that are 1260 to the value of the canvas width minus the width of the ellipse

Comment: What code do you have?

Comment: @GlenThomas Added all the code, have a look